# $.get to retrieve YouTube video using google API returning nothing in IE

Tags: json, internet-explorer, google-api, youtube, youtube-data-api

Below is the code that I have in order to retrieve YouTube videos using Google API:

```
                   $.get(
                   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
                   part : 'snippet', 
                   q:searchKey,
                   maxResults:3,
                   type:'video',
                   channelId:'Ufdefew3E0iGDp-5OmR8Ddww',
                   order:'date',
                   key: apiKey},
                   function(data) {                 
                      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                     .............
                          }
                      });
```

This code is returning nothing in any of my IE browsers but I see it working in chrome and FF. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IE8 or IE9, it's because although IE8 and IE9 *do* support [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (which you need for that request to work), they don't support it using the usual `XMLHttpRequest` object; instead, you have to use the `XDomainRequest` object. jQuery doesn't cover over this particular cross-browser issue for you, so `$.get` won't work with CORS on IE8 and IE9.

If you search, there's a patch or plugin for jQuery that will make it work with IE8 or IE9.

IE10 and up support CORS properly (I don't know if that's true when the page is being displayed in the massively-misnamed "compatibility" mode; in*tra*net pages *are* by default, so if you're testing locally in IE10 and having trouble, that could be it — tell IE not to show intranet pages in compatibility mode). The `X-UA-Compatible` meta header may also come into play here. (When using any advanced features, I tend to include `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` near the top of `head`.)

IE7 and below don't support CORS at all.

Comment: Hi, should it work in IE 10+ without any plugin? if not do you know any plugins that would do the job? Thanks

Comment: @user318197 It works in IE10+. It *may* be problematic if you're in "compatibility mode," see update above. I don't know, I haven't tested that personally, but if Chrome and Firefox work and IE10 doesn't, that's the first thing I'd check for.

Comment: Holy God!!!! Thanks a lots man :) The document mode of the browser was  9. It worked after I changed it.

Comment: @user318197: Fantastic! And that's useful to know, thanks. :-)